# "[Errno 5] Input/output error" during installation

Tags: system-installation

I realize there are a few questions like this but - without answer...
The only one like this with answer is from 2014 and the instructions there are no longer applicable.

I have a Clevo laptop with an NVMe PCIe SSD. I know these laptops are usually fine with Ubuntu, because they are actually designed around it.

I downloaded ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso from ubuntu.com (I don't think there was any mirror involved).

I validated the download:

```
echo "93bdab204067321ff131f560879db46bee3b994bf24836bb78538640f689e58f *ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop- 
amd64.iso" | shasum -a 256 --check

ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
```

I followed the instructions from here:
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#4-boot-selection-and-partition-scheme

When I booted from the USB stick, I saw it was "checking disk" and then started the installation.

I chose "erase disk and install". The previous OS on that laptop was win10

"Conveniently", after the installer erased my OS, it apparently found some "corrupt CD/DVD" with the error message containing "[Errno 5] Input/output error"

This happened at the "almost done copying files" stage

I have reproduced this a few times now, using a different USB stick.

I thought about checking my disk somehow but this looks crazy-complex...

Any ideas where to start investigating, in order to install Ubuntu without errors?

Comment: honestly disappointed with Ubuntu. In 2021, still can't provide a reasonable beginner experience. I am a backend developer for 15 years now, most of my stuff is deployed on CentOS servers, which I administer happily...

Comment: It's amazing Ubuntu installer isn't integrated but you have to download 3'rd party software to create a bootable USB... It's amazing the installer can't detect any problems **BEFORE** it destroys the existing OS and can't recover or even provide basic idea of what went wrong... The laptop was going to be me parting ways with MS but it seems like it's going back to the seller...

Comment: Start investigating your hardware: A faulty USB port or SSD.

Comment: USB memory sticks have no self-validation, self-diagnostics or integrity functions, the are made to provide maximum capacity and be cheap.  Failures with them occur (even if it passes sometimes), and I consider them necessary but somewhat untrustworthy devices (*I'm writing ~300 ISOs to thumb-drive a year so I see more failures than most probably do*).  I'd verify the stick on another box (of same type (uEFI/Secure-uEFI/BIOS), plus a different type to ensure media is good, if they all pass - then I'd consider looking for something other than *suspect* thumb-drive.

Comment: as I said, multiple sticks have been tried... I've actually solved the problem. It's definitely some bug with the installer. I will post answer when SE lets me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following and it is clearly the issue. We can continue talking about file/usb corruption but at this point I know the hash code by heart and tried 6 sticks.

During one of the many attempts to install this OS, I was just lazy to provide the wifi password and proceeded without internet ("download updates" was grayed-out).
Result: The installation completed without issues

I didn't stop there, I tried another installation, with the internet ON = "[errno 5..."

I then wanted to finalize, actually have an OS on my laptop, took the internet off during the installation - again, completed without issues

Therefore, this is an answer for me and potentially useful for other users who struggle and have tried other things

Comment: I don't think this question/answer should be merged with the existing questions, as they clearly didn't apply to my case - but SE mods will do what SE mods feel like doing...Anyway, I am happy so I don't care :)

Answer (score 2):

The `[Errno 5] Input/output error` message has dozens of answers on this very site. A quick Google search (or Bing if you prefer) can validate this. The issue generally happens when one of two situations occur:

1. the installation media is faulty
2. (if the installation is via USB) the USB port loses power during the installation, causing an I/O error

The Ubuntu Installer can do quite a bit of pre-testing if you're booting first into a Live session, *then* installing the OS. If you elect to install the operating system from the command line without first testing the Live session, that's on the person driving the computer.

To resolve Lou Bega's "Error Number 5", you have a couple of options:

1. Try using a different USB port. It's a very 1999 solution, but it is still valid in this day and age
2. Use a different installation medium.
   ⇢ If the USB stick is indeed bad, then it cannot be trusted.
   ⇢ If the USB stick is fine, but the copy of the `.iso` was bad, then the source files cannot be trusted.

Hope this points you in the right direction

Comment: well I did, as stated, made sure to validate the ISO and try different sticks... I will try Live Session first - although I respectfully disagree that a basic function not working is somehow the users fault. At no point during installation did the installer tell me "oh, this option doesn't work, don't chose this, go to Live Session" - how was I supposed to know that, other then get a few minuses on StackExchange? :D

Comment: thanks for your time though. I sincerely appreciate it!