# Errno 5 error input/output during installation off Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04

This error occurs during installation off Ubuntu, the hard disk is ok, I controlled it in the disk utility tool of Ubuntu in the try-version. I’ve searched the whole internet but I can’t find the solution. The hard-disk is a new Samsung SSD with 2T memory, thanks all ready, Severine

Comment: You didn't provide the full message (*nor which Ubuntu 22.04 product you're using*), but my guess from your title is that you're having trouble due to invalid ISO or more likely in my opinion, bad write to your installation media.  Did the installation media validate successfully for your *unstated* 22.04 product?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)   *please note the media check answer maybe more worthwhile; as it's the bit I think most applies here*  or maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311183/do-i-need-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-ubuntu-install

Comment: Have you updated SSD with latest firmware, even new drives may need update. My Samsung NVMe drive had an update ISO which only was for my model drive. https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/
Look at firmware, not Magician which is Windows.This will show current model & serial number: `udisksctl status` or `sudo nvme list` if NVMe drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["\[Errno 5\] Input/output error" during installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1318998/errno-5-input-output-error-during-installation)